# How do I get the canvas size in a java applet from Graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, applet, size

The code that I have now gives me the size of the applet, not the size of the drawing area. How could I fix that?

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 
    g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
    g.fillRect(5, 5, getWidth()-5, getHeight()-5);

}
```

Comment: You don't get it *from* the Graphics object, you call `getSize()` or `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the applet itself, the `this` object.

Comment: Could you, please, also call super.paint(g); This is very important and will prevent a lot of issues in the future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emm... I guess you are trying to paint right in JApplet so you should have applet and canvas been separated

use code conception like a

```
class MyCanvas extends JPanel
{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{ 
    g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
    g.fillRect(5, 5, getWidth()-5, getHeight()-5);

}

}
```

and applet...

```
public class MyApplet extends JApplet
{

public void init()
{
  this.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
}

}
```

P.S.
Report if that was helpful